# ROS: Display sensor_msgs/Image image form a custom topic

Tags: ros, rospy

I have a problem with debugging my ROS code. I can't display an image to verify proper tracking.

Is there an easy way to display images from a custom message using a terminal, or do I have to write a new node that will display the image?

My message:

`std_msgs/Header header` 
`uint64[] object_ids` 
`uint16[] class_ids` 
`float32[] confs` 
`int16[] x_coords` 
`int16[] y_coords` 
`int16[] bb_width` 
`int16[] bb_hight` 
`sensor_msgs/Image source_image`

I want to display `source_image` coming from a topic `/tracker_topic`.

I tried using `topic_tools relay_field`, but I'm using python 3 which doesn't use Unicode, and I'm getting errors because of that.

Comment: "*easy way to display images from a custom message*" why you don't use RViz?